# How to change the background color conditionally according to row values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, colors

I am developing a report which outputs data in a SQL Table via an ASPX page, using VB.  How do I code this so that all rows containing a "1" for one of the columns, shows up as red?  Here is what I have so far.  This doesn't cause any errors, but it doesn't show up as red either.

I don't know if this is a problem, but the ExceedsLimit and SixInARow variables are INTs in my stored procs, but then I am declaring them as strings in the code below.

```
    Private Sub DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs)
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
            Dim ExceedsLimit As String
            Dim SixInARow As String
            Dim i As Int16

            SixInARow = e.Item.Cells(6).Text
            ExceedsLimit = e.Item.Cells(7).Text

            If ExceedsLimit = "1" Or SixInARow = "1" Then
                For i = 0 To 6
                    e.Item.Cells(i).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                Next
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
```

And the HTML portion:

```
            <ASP:DATAGRID id="dgTable" runat="server" AUTOGENERATECOLUMNS="true" ShowHeader="true" OnItemDataBound="DataGrid1_ItemDataBound" >
                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor = "#eeeeee" />
                <HEADERSTYLE BackColor = "#336699" ForeColor = "#ffffff" Font-Bold = "true" />
            </ASP:DATAGRID>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the background color to the Item.Style

Try this:

```
If ExceedsLimit = "1" Or SixInARow = "1" Then                 
  e.Item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red                 
End If
```

Comment: Thanks!  I just tried your code above, but still none of the rows appeared as red.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to Trim the ExceedsLimit and SixInaRow before comparing.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work either.  Thanks for trying though!